# Can I share tags between 2 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying this gem but there is a situation where 2 models should share tags (so if one is created on model1, it should be available on model2).

Is this possible or should I create a model that allows me to keep tags for both models in a single place?

**Example**

```
class Hikes < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Name
  # Date
  # Hikers[*]
  # ...
  acts_as_taggable_on :event_types
end

class Events < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Name
  # Date
  # Note
  acts_as_taggable_on :event_types
end
```

I would like to share event_types "group" of tags between the two models. Expecially because I would like to create a something similar to the stackoverflow tag field (so with tag count to see how many times it has been used). Obviusly the tags_count should be shared between the two models.

**Note:** The Hike is actually an event (that's why they share the same group of tags) that is handled differently through the application because there are more things that I have to handle.

Comment: Sounds like a nice requirement. Could you please add an example about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: you should be able to use the same tags, but have two through models.

Comment: @lucapette I added the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very incomplete.

Assuming that you have ActiveRecord models for the two "models" and the tags, this structure could work:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :b
end
```

Comment: That is what I thought, I'm testing with it but I would like to avoid this approach

Comment: Added an example as asked, hopefully can help with your answer.

Comment: That's the only possible way at the moment. I must say that the plugin doesn't support this so.